# Catching the Vegetable-Goose

Tags: mathematics, geometry, strategy, pursuit-evasion

After an altercation involving giant bees, you have been sentence to some hard labour, specifically harvesting barnacle-lambs: a gourd-like fruit that grows geese in its shell

While working, you get an overripe fruit that is old enough to fly. Based on its appearance it should be able to hover about at 1m/s for about 10s. It also seems pretty unintelligent, and will only fly directly away from you. You're pretty quick, but you've also been chained to your post with a 5m long chain. Currently it is already 1m ahead of you and your post

What is the minimum speed you'd need to retain in order to keep the fruit from leaving the area where you can reach it?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of words are confusing:

By "hover" I assume you mean it's moving (generally means to stay in place)

By "retain" I assume you mean some kind of average speed needed.  Clearly our speed will accelerate and not be maintained as a constant.

So, maybe:

> If I am even with the post (as assumed is meant by "1m ahead of you and your post") and it is 1m away from me, heading directly away from me, in 4 meters (and thus 4 seconds) it will leave the area I can reach it.  So I have 4 seconds to go 5 meters and must go at a minimum speed of 1.25m/s (average).